# What is the reason to quote executable code with `.........'?

Tags: shell, c

I was reading through the [original bourne shell signal handling implementation](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/sh/xec.c) and noticed an expression inside a comment was quoted this way:

```
/* `stakbot' is preserved by this routine */
   ^^^^^^^^
```

also the [zsh user guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html)

> The command `bye' is identical to `exit'

and IIRC the zsh man pages use this same notation.
Why?

Is it to prevent the code from being accidentally being interpreted as a backtick expression and executed ?
or is it simply a convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just using the backtick as an opening quote; it's the equivalent of

> ‘stakbot’ is preserved by this routine

and

> The command ‘bye’ is identical to ‘exit’

using only ASCII characters.

Comment: thanks, so it is simply a convention of quoting when writing documentation and comments? i.e. there is no significance to a parser or from a syntax point of view?

Comment: In the contexts you've given (a comment in C code, and HTML documentation), there is no significance for a parser. (Even in other contexts, there isn't much significance, at least within comments or documentation; ` and ' are explicitly defined as opening and closing quotes in TeX, I'm not sure about nroff.)

Comment: thanks, at first I didn't notice you had used different opening and closing quotes in this line: `‘stakbot’`. So essentially when you don't have access to those characters  - and you want to use a quote which is specifically for opening and another for closing - `\`....'` is a kind of DIY way of achieving that. cool, thanks.